# Criar Xpath manualmente

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Estou testando um site que roda apenas e exclusivamente no Internet Explorer, sendo assim não posso utilizar o Firebug, alguém sabe como posso criar um Xpath de um elemento manualmente ou conhece alguma ferramenta para o IE que identifique este Xpath, semelhante ao Firebug (o IE Dev Tools não faz este trabalho, ja o utilizo).

Com o código HTML abaixo, Eu ja cheguei a dois Xpaths, mas o Sleenium não consegue clicar em nenhum deles (ja tentei pelo nome e id e não clica tbm, por isso a necessidade do Xpath).

`/html/body/center/table/tr[7]/td[1]/input/button` e `/html/body/center/table/tr[7]/td[1]/input/`

Preciso identificar o Xpath dobotão "OK"

```
 <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="2">
            <input name="btnClose" type="button" class="button" value='OK'                      onclick="javascript:abrirSimulador();window.close();" />
        </td>
    </tr>


<html>
<head>
<title>
[Ativação] - Pré-Análise de Crédito
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ativacao/js/jquery_noConflict.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    J(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
        abrirSimulador();
    })
</script>

<center><!-- Início da Página --> <!-- Título da Página --> <br>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="350">
    <tr>
        <td class="page-title">Pré-Análise de Crédito</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="page-subtitle">Mensagem de Informação</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="300" >
    <tr>
        <td class="label" align="right">
            Código da operação: &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="text">
        002PjPr
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- OS 81138 - Inicio -->

    <tr>
        <td class="label" align="right">
            Pontos: &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="text">
        1,00
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" align="right">
            Limite:  &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="text">
        1500,00
        </td>
    </tr>

        <!-- OS 81138 - Fim -->

    <!-- OS Unificação Cadastral II -->
    <tr>
        <td class="label" align="right">
            Cliente America Movel:  &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="text">

            Sim


        </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- OS Unificação Cadastral II -->
    <tr>
        <td class="label" align="right">
            Resposta:  &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="text">
        Prosseguir
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label" align="right">
            Justificativa:  &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="text">
            Limite calculado. Favor prosseguir com a venda
        </td>
    </tr>
    c
</table>

</center>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function abrirSimulador(){
    window.opener.prosseguirAnaliseCredito = false;

    if(window.opener.scorePreAnalise){
        window.opener.prosseguirAnaliseCredito = true;
        window.opener.checkAssociateSimularPrecoPreAnalise(window.opener.simulatePopup);
        return;
    }
    window.opener.scorePreAnalise = false;

}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Resolvido utilizando o AutoIt.

Comment: No seu caso, acredito que o `xpath //input[@value='OK']` seria suficiente para localizar o botão.

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se já solucionou seu problema, mas se seus `names` e `id` são únicos já tentou escrever seu xpath tipo assim: `.//*[@name='btnClose']` ?